# Why regular module import routing module instead of reverse

Tags: angular

I'm confusing  why `NomalModule` import the `NormalRoutingModule` instead of   `NormalRoutingModule`  import `NomalModule`  . for example a angular project normally create like this

```
app.module.ts  --> AppModule --> import AppRoutingModule
app.routing.module.ts --> AppRoutingModule
my.module.ts ----> MyModule  ---> import MyRoutingModule
my.routing.module.ts->  MyRoutingModule
```

From what I think, it'll be more flexiable if the routing module import normal module .

should the `AppRoutingModule` import `AppModule` and `MyRoutingModule` import `MyModule`  so the component of Url is relate to routing module , and the `MyModule` can be reuse without create duplicate url .

for example :
 `My2Module` use a compoent from `MyModule`, and `My2Module` has it's own url routing ,  it will be two set of url for My2Module if `MyModule` import `MyRoutingModule`. and it'll be ok if `MyRoutingModule` import `MyModule` because MyModule won't contains routing any more.

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: @Ramesh  can u understand now ?